# Looping over results with MongoDB and Lithium

Tags: php, mongodb, lithium

I've just started using Lithium and have come across a (probably very simple...) problem where I can't iterate over the results of a simple query. I have compared my code to various samples and I can't see any differences but something must be!

```
// Controller
namespace app\controllers;

use app\models\POI;

class POIsController extends \lithium\action\Controller {

    public function index($category) {

       $data = POI::find('all', array('limit' => 10));

       $this->set(array('data' => $data));
    }
}



// Model
namespace app\models;

class POI extends \lithium\data\Model {
    protected $_meta = array(
        'source' => 'POI'
    );
}



// View
print $data->count(); // outputs 10

foreach($data as $poi):?>
    <?php print $poi->Name;?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The loop in the View only displays the first item's Name field and misses out the other 9 which are apparently there.

Does anyone have any ideas about why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always the answer pops up just after asking the question...

My model doesn't have the usual ID set up (it has key in field "ID") so I had to add that to the schema and the meta data otherwise I guess all the models were thought to have the same empty key and so wouldn't iterate.

Updated Model code:

```
namespace app\models;

class POI extends \lithium\data\Model {
    protected $_meta = array(
        'source' => 'POI',
        'key' => 'ID'
    );

    public $_schema = array(
        'ID' => array('type'=>'id'),
        'Name' => array('type'=>'string','null'=>false)
    );

}
```

Hope this can help someone else in the future!